# Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, internationalization, react-i18next

Implementing "I18n.js" in our React Native project has worked flawlessly until a couple of days ago. Through the use of "Crashalytics" with Firebase we have noticed repeated but few crashes. These crashes seem to only mainly occur on Android 11 and Samsung + Xiomi devices (none on iPhones yet). The log output is as follows:

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 's.languageTag'), stack:

   at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:83)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:188)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:226)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I fail to reproduce the crash by changing language in the phone, downloading hardware profiles that match the ones mentioned in the crash logs (Samsung S10, etc), and using them as the emulator.
Any help and/or ideas are much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: same here! could you find any solution? thanks

Comment: We had the same/similar issue and were able to reproduce it by increasing the size of the text on the device in settings.

Comment: @Sloth87 Thank you for your suggestion! I will definitely try this out next time I have an android device! Did you experience the same errors when using an iPhone or only on Android as my crash reports indicate? :) 

Did you manage to solve it after you could reproduce the error and how in that case? :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. You can debug it by running production build on your phone and connect it with Android studio. You can see the logs by selecting your phone and app process [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SST2I.png). I my case the error was about destructuring a property that doesn't exist in object